# If I copied an app script from online and saved it as a project, when allowing permission, does the original creator of the app script get access?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-slides

I found a script online that allows you to change the font on all Google Slides at once. I copied it from online and when I run it in Google Slides, it asks if I should allow access to my Google Account. Since I copied the script, if I click "allow" will the original creator of the script get access? Or is it just me who will get access since I saved the script as a project?

Comment: Hi, @Jessica. Could you please share the code in your post? So it is easier to understand what the script will do.

Comment: Yes, the script is from here: https://gist.github.com/dsottimano/20a50daded2128b4c86acb430cecba67

Comment: That code will not grant access to the original creator.

Comment: Thank you! How do you know it won't grant access?

Comment: The code does not call any google service that will share/send information to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The script/code, you copy/pasted will get access. What that code does with the access depends on what is written in it.